# Intermittent 'NoAuthHandlerFound' boto error | django + kinesis client

Tags: python, django, boto3, boto, amazon-kinesis

Even after trying solution for: [Boto3 intermittent NoAuthHandlerFound errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312799/boto3-intermittent-noauthhandlerfound-errors) getting following error:

```
[Tue Aug 04 12:55:09.460312 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24727:tid 140597795952384]     creds = self._get_credentials_from_metadata(metadata)
[Tue Aug 04 12:55:09.460342 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24727:tid 140597795952384]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/boto/provider.py", line 424, in _get_credentials_from_metadata
[Tue Aug 04 12:55:09.460373 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24727:tid 140597795952384]     "%s" % (msg))
[Tue Aug 04 12:55:09.460415 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24727:tid 140597795952384] boto.exception.InvalidInstanceMetadataError: Expected a dict type of credentials instead received an empty string
[Tue Aug 04 12:55:09.460450 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 24727:tid 140597795952384] You can set the 'metadata_service_num_attempts' in your boto config file to increase the number of times boto will attempt to retrieve credentials from the instance metadata service.
```

I have set `AWS_METADATA_SERVICE_NUM_ATTEMPTS` to 4 in both on the machine & in django settings.py. When I try manual retry in code, it works but is taking too long to respond and requests get queued up throwing 502, 503 errors.

Note: Authentication is via IAM role.

Comment: what version of boto3 or botocore?

Comment: @Lamanus   boto==2.49.0

Comment: Why just boto? Try with boto3

Comment: I tried with boto3 initially, I am running a Django API & my response time increased with boto3(900ms) hence I switched to boto(300ms response time).